# Guess the date only giving the time when it's around the midnight hours

Tags: c#, php, datetime, timer, stopwatch

I'm developing a form where the user can insert the start and stop times of a list of services, but it's a requirement that only the hours and minutes are inserted.

Also that there's an overall start/stop (in a disabled input) just for viewing purposes.
Additionally, I need to save a DateTime in the database, giving that the day is today or tomorrow. I'm going to explain a use case so you can better understand my problem.

#### Example 1: Raw times

```json
{
  "overall": {
    "start": "20:30",
    "stop": "00:30"
  },
  "services": {
    "1": {
      "start": "20:30",
      "stop": "21:00"
    },
    "2": {
      "start": "23:35",
      "stop": "23:55"
    },
    "3": {
      "start": "23:45",
      "stop": "00:10"
    },
    "4": {
      "start": "00:05",
      "stop": "00:30"
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say that the first service starts at 20:30 and the last one starts at 00:05.

Ignoring the day, of course that the one that starts at 00:05 would be considered as the first one started, but actually that's not correct case because 00:05 is actually inside the "tomorrow" time.

How can I do this so I can have a code like the example below?
(language-agnostic, but if you prefer to show a code example, C# or PHP would be fine)

#### Example 2: Converted times

```json
{
  "overall": {
    "start": "2017/07/05 20:30",
    "stop": "2017/07/06 00:30"
  },
  "services": {
    "1": {
      "start": "2017/07/05 20:30",
      "stop": "2017/07/05 21:00"
    },
    "2": {
      "start": "2017/07/05 23:35",
      "stop": "2017/07/05 23:55"
    },
    "3": {
      "start": "2017/07/05 23:45",
      "stop": "2017/07/06 00:10"
    },
    "4": {
      "start": "2017/07/06 00:05",
      "stop": "2017/07/06 00:30"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you save the full datetime object you know it has to fire tomorrow...

Comment: Just store the start time followed by a "duration" timespan value rather than an absolute datetime or time-of-day value.

Comment: @EpicKip, this data is inserted by a user. You can't force a user to insert a datetime. He's only inserting a hh:mm and nothing else.

Comment: @oscarmarcelo So what you are asking is: here are the raw times how to convert them to date as well so the order is correct? -edit- I read it 2x more and now understand. was reading it too fast i think

Comment: How would that data look in c#? an index, start and stop time? (as class)

Comment: @EpicKip The data is sent via Ajax. The example 1 is the actual structure. The json.services is the data sent and each value is read as a string. Is this what you asking?

Comment: @oscarmarcelo I rarely work with json so I was wondering what it would look like in c# code if I made the data myself. (eg. a class and a list of objects?) that way i can solve it

Comment: This is just an example. I'm giving you freedom to interpret the way you prefer. I just need is an algorithm to increase the day when the time is after midnight, giving only a list of times in just hh:mm.